# Errors in prototype in C++ in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

This is what I have in my header file.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> i_list;
￼class Matrix {
  public:
    Matrix(uint rows, uint cols);
    Matrix(const i_list & list);
    Matrix(const Matrix & m);
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix add(double s) const;
    Matrix add(const Matrix & m) const;
    Matrix subtract(double s) const;
    Matrix subtract(const Matrix & m) const;
    Matrix multiply(double s) const;
    Matrix multiply(const Matrix & m) const;
    Matrix divide(double s) const;
    Matrix t() const;
    const uint numRows() const;
    const uint numCols() const;
    double & at(uint row, uint col);
    const double & at (uint row, uint col) const; // get element at row,col (when using a const object)
}; // Matrix
```

XCode is telling me line `typedef initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> i_list;` has an `Unknown type name 'initializer_list'` and `Expected unqualified-id` errors.

`class Matrix {` has a`Unknown type name 'class'` error.

`public:` has a `Expected expression` error.

Might this be a XCode issue with circular dependency?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <initializer_list>` to use `std::initializer_list`.

`Unknown type name 'class'` sounds as if you were not compiling your code as C++.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the initializer_list issues. XCode is building as C++ header according to file inspecter.